# Query to join 4 tables with foreign key and group by dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I trying to join 4 tables. I the way that I will receive list of products showing sales and claims registered in each month.
There are 4 combinations to be taken into account:

1. Product have been sold in certain month and we have claim for it.
2. Product haven't been sold certain month and we have a claim for it.
3. Product have been sold in certain month and we do not have claims for it.
4. Product haven't been sold certain month and we do not have claims for it.

   I'm starting to think that creating date table might by necessary.

```
select
   ps.date,
   cl.date,
   ps.part_number,
   ps.sales_quantity,
   cl.claims_quantity
from (select convert(varchar(7), s.date, 120) as date, p.part_number, sum(id.quantity) as sales_quantity
   from parts as p
   left outer join invoice_details as id
   on p.part_number = id.part_number
   left outer join sales as s
   on id.invoice = s.invoice
   group by convert(varchar(7), s.date, 120), p.part_number
   ) ps join 
   (select convert(varchar(7), c.date_registered, 120) as date, p.part_number, sum(c.quantity) as claims_quantity
   from parts as p
   left outer join claims as c
   on p.part_number = c.part_number
   group by convert(varchar(7), c.date_registered, 120), p.part_number
   ) cl
   on ps.part_number = cl.part_number
group by ps.date, cl.date, ps.part_number, ps.sales_quantity, cl.claims_quantity
order by cl.claims_quantity desc
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a row for each part and month.  If so, you need some method of generating the months -- because they may not be in the data.

Then, use a `left join` to bring in the data and aggregation to get the information you want:

```
select p.part_number, m.mon,
       sum(sales_quantity), sum(claim_quantity)
from parts p cross join
     (select date('2020-01-01') as mon union all
      select date('2020-02-01') as mon 
     ) m left join
     ((select s.date, id.part_number, id.quantity as sale_quantity, null as claim_quantity
       from sales s join
            invoice_details id
            on id.id_sale = s.id_sale
      ) union all
      (select c.date_registered, null, null, quantity
       from claims
      )
     ) sc
     on sc.part_number = p.part_number and
        sc.date >= m.mon and
        sc.date < m.mon + interval 1 month
group by p.part_number, m.mon
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make separate date table?

Comment: @starylass . . . If you have one on hand, use it.  I'm trying to demonstrate the logic for answering your question.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. A suppose that date function comes from oracle.

Comment: @starylass . . . Oracle has nothing to do with this answer.  The question is tagged MySQL.  `date()` is part of MySQL.

Comment: I have checked that but it is not giving correct results. I cannot find reason why.

Comment: It seems to give sale quantity not from whole month but only from first day of month.

Comment: @starylass . . . There was a typo in the `on` clause.  The first comparison should be `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

Code below is not giving correct results

````
declare @date1 date='2019-02-01';
declare @date2 date='2019-03-01';
declare @date3 date='2019-04-01';
declare @date4 date='2019-05-01';
declare @date5 date='2019-06-01';
declare @date6 date='2019-07-01';
declare @date7 date='2019-08-01';
declare @date8 date='2019-09-01';
declare @date9 date='2019-10-01';
declare @date10 date='2019-11-01';
declare @date11 date='2019-12-01';

select p.part_number, m.mon,
       sum(sales_quantity) AS SALES, sum(claim_quantity) AS CLAIMS
from parts p cross join 
     (select @date as mon union all
     select @date1 as mon union all
     select @date2 as mon union all
     select @date3 as mon union all
     select @date4 as mon union all
     select @date5 as mon union all
     select @date6 as mon union all
     select @date7 as mon union all
     select @date8 as mon union all
     select @date9 as mon union all
     select @date10 as mon union all
     select @date11 as mon
     ) m left join
     ((select s.date, id.part_number, id.quantity as sales_quantity, null as claim_quantity
       from sales s join
            invoice_details id
            on id.invoice = s.invoice
      ) union all
      (select date_registered, part_number, null, quantity
       from claims 
      )
     ) sc
     on sc.part_number = p.part_number and
        sc.date = m.mon and 
        sc.date < DATEADD(MONTH, +1, m.mon)
    where sc.part_number = 'TC1133' 
group by p.part_number, m.mon```
````